# Eclipse SVN Commit "fails" after upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ubuntu, configuration

while upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04LTS to 12.04LTS, we kept all necessary configurationfiles (svn, trac, apache2) alive. At first all seemed working fine. We could still connect to Trac and SVN using latest version of subclipse 1.8.18, check out and update files, but when it comes to committing changes to SVN, all clients always get the following message:

```
    RA layer request failed
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: MERGE of '/svn/some/path': 200 OK (http://our.server.ip.here)
```

The weird thing is, that committing the data is actually working, but eclipse somehow doesn't recognize this, which obviously has to do with the error showed above. I checked several configuration files, compared those with several guides, "how to install svn/trac to ubuntu", but all seems fine. I also tried to Team-Cleanup and Refresh my projects, like suggested in other posts who had the same problem, without success.

Can anyone point me in the right direction concerning this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone should ever have the same problem, here how we solved it:

During the upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 LTS, Ubuntu reinstalled trac Version 0.12, instead of keeping Version 1.xx . This caused our CommitHooks to fail, because trac 0.12 does not support multiple projects.

After reupgrading trac from Version 0.12 to 1.xx, it worked fine again!